# Setting up a micropayment system to pay others to do tasks on my website

Tags: paypal, mechanicalturk, flattr

I have a website where people do simple cognitive psychology experiments. Currently, people volunteer. To increase numbers of responses, I would like to offer micropayments in a manner similar to Mechanical Turk*. 
My question is, What would would be the best system to use to make these payments? I would guess that both paypal and flattr would be options. Has anyone with experience with setting up a micropayment system like this be able to offer advice?
cheers,
Mark

*I am not thinking about using mechanical turk itself, just because I do not think I would be able to control the web based studies exactly I would need.

Comment: I think this is more a business problem and not so much a programming issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Flattr would work in your scenario:

- Each person doing the test would need a Flattr account.
- They’d need to login with their Flattr account on your site (like on fundd.de) or connect your site with their Flattr (easy with OAuth).
- Once they’ve taken the test you manually Flattr them and by controlling your monthly budget you control how much each click is worth.

Our API makes setting this up fairly easy and straightforward http://developers.flattr.net/

Downsides:

- Required to sign up with an additional service.
- Flattr currently caps monthly spending at €100 so if you have lots and lots of testers you’d run into problems of making the payment high enough. We are reconsidering this, at least for users in good standing.
- Monetary incentives for testers bring in a different crowd and can influence the results of their tests but you probably already know that.

Cheers,

Teller

PS. I work at Flattr.